# Mass Energy Equation Derivation?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, special-relativity, energy, mass-energy

I am reading the derivation from Einstein's paper [DOES THE INERTIA OF A BODY DEPEND
UPON ITS ENERGY-CONTENT?](https://www.fourmilab.ch/etexts/einstein/E_mc2/e_mc2.pdf).

In the end of page 2, he derives that

$$K_0 - K_1 = L\{\frac{1}{\sqrt{1 - v^2/c^2}} - 1\}.$$

The next line he immediately has

$$K_0 - K_1 = \frac{1}{2}\frac{L}{c^2}v^2.$$

I guess he is using Taylor expansion, but can someone show in detail how he reaches this step?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should use the following Taylor expansion

$$\frac{1}{{\sqrt {1 - {\varepsilon ^2}} }} = 1 + \frac{1}{2}{\varepsilon ^2} + \frac{3}{8}{\varepsilon ^4} + O({\varepsilon ^6}),$$

where $\varepsilon=v/c$. This is a series expansion around $\varepsilon=v/c=0$, meaning that the speed of particle is much smaller than the speed of light$ (v \ll c$). Having this and ignoring higher order approximations $O(\varepsilon ^4)$, you can quickly obtain the final result.

Comment: Question: if $K_0 - K_1 = \frac{1}{2}\frac{L}{c^2}v^2$ is derived by Taylor expansion up to $O(\epsilon^2)$, does that mean $E = mc^2$ is an approximation?

Comment: @ZEWEICHU $E = m c^2$ is valid only in the rest frame of the object. The formula that is correct in any frame is $E=\gamma m c^2$ with $\gamma$ the inverse relativistic square root. Try tailor-expanding this around $v=0$ to get the Newtonian kinetic energy term

Comment: @ZEWEICHU - The short answer is no. As  Prof. Legolasov mentioned, $E=m c^2$ is the relativistic energy in the rest frame of the object. On the other hand, $\frac{{m{c^2}}}{{\sqrt {1 - {v^2}/{c^2}} }}$ is the relativistic energy of the moving object (with the speed $v$ with respect to the observer). Using these definitions, the relativistic kinetic energy is defined as ${K_{relativistic}} = \frac{{m{c^2}}}{{\sqrt {1 - {v^2}/{c^2}} }} - m{c^2}$. Up to $O({\varepsilon ^2})$, this relation reduces to the well-known kinetic energy in Newtonian mechanics.

Comment: I think my main confusion is that, in Einstein's [paper](https://www.fourmilab.ch/etexts/einstein/E_mc2/e_mc2.pdf), he states that the kinetic energy of an object after emission of light decreases by $L\{\frac{1}{\sqrt{1 - \frac{v^2}{c^2}}} - 1\} = \frac{1}{2}\frac{L}{c^2}v^2 = \frac{1}{2}mv^2$. Then we reach the conclusion that $\frac{L}{c^2} = m$. However, since the first step in the equation is by Taylor expansion up to $O(\epsilon^2)$, isn't that just an approximation? If I understand correctly, Einstein did not mention anything about $\frac{mc^2}{\sqrt{1 - v^2/c^2}}$.

Comment: I saw many other notes mention relativistic energy, etc, but I am trying to follow what Einstein was thinking in his paper.